# Running asp.net site on Windows Server 2003 and accessing it over LAN

Tags: asp.net

I want to run an ASP.Net application on Windows Server 2003 and access it over a LAN.
Like http://serverIP/sitename.com

How do I do this? What configuration changes should I make to IIS?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 scenarios (assuming you want/have to use IP's in the URL):

1. You site is the only web-site running on your web-server - you can set up your site with the default port 80 binding, i.e. you don't specify a host name or IP address. This means any request on port 80 will route to your site (remember to stop or delete the "Default" web site, as it normally has the default port 80 binding)
2. You have multiple sites running on your server - you need to assign an additional IP address for that server and specifically use that IP in the http binding for you site.